# Why is Pygame coming up as a black screen

Tags: python, pygame

Ok so basically the screen comes up wanting my name input and when I enter it the pygame window opens up however when it does it is just a black screen and it does not come up with an error either.
Any ideas guys? :)

```
import time

import random`enter code here`
import pygame
from pygame import*
pygame.init()
myname=input('What is your name')
#set the window size
window= pygame.display.set_mode((800,600) ,0,24)
pygame.display.set_caption("Fruit Catch")
#game variables
myscore=0
mylives=3
mouth_x=300
fruit_x=250
fruit_y=75
fruitlist=['chicken.gif','broccoli.gif']
#prepare for screen
myfont=pygame.font.SysFont("Britannic Bold", 55)
label1=myfont.render(myname, 1, (240, 0, 0))

label3=myfont.render(str(mylives), 1, (20, 255, 0))
#grapchics
fruit=pygame.image.load('data/chicken.gif')
mouth=pygame.image.load('data/bowl.gif')
backGr=pygame.image.load('data/kfc.jpg')
#endless loop
running=True
while running:
   #code to move fruit
    if fruit_y>=460:#check if at bottom, if so prepare new fruit
      fruit_x=random.randrange(50,530,1)
      fruit_y=75
      fruit=pygame.image.load('data/'+fruitlist[random.randrange(0,2,1)])
    else:fruit_y+=5
   #check collision
    if fruit_y>=440:
           if fruit_x>=mouth_x and fruit_x<=mouth_x+110:
                              myscore+1
                              fruit_y=600 #move it off screen
            #detect key events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
                     if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):
                         if (event.key==pygame.K_LEFT):
                                 mouth_x-=20
                         if (event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT):
                                 mouth_x+=20
#update screen from back first
label2=myfont.render(str(myscore), 1, (20, 255, 0))
window.blit(backGr,(0,0))
window.blit(mouth, (mouth_x,440))
window.blit(fruit,(fruit-x, fruit_y))
window.blit(label1, (174, 537))
window.blit(label2, (700, 157))
window.blit(label3, (700, 400))
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: your screen update code should be inside your while loop?

Comment: Make sure that the code you have placed here is indented correctly.

Comment: Your updating your screen after your while loop stops running (at least with how you currently have it indented).

Answer (score 3):

Use this properly indented code...
Note that in addition to indentation there are other very silly mistakes that you were doing

=> `myscore+1` does nothing.
=> `window.blit(fruit,(fruit-x, fruit_y))` has `fruit-x` instead of `fruit_x`

```
import time
import random
import pygame
from pygame import*
pygame.init()
myname=input('What is your name')
#set the window size
window= pygame.display.set_mode((800,600) ,0,24)
pygame.display.set_caption("Fruit Catch")
#game variables
myscore=0
mylives=3
mouth_x=300
fruit_x=250
fruit_y=75
fruitlist=['chicken.gif','b.gif']
#prepare for screen
myfont=pygame.font.SysFont("Britannic Bold", 55)
label1=myfont.render(myname, 1, (240, 0, 0))

label3=myfont.render(str(mylives), 1, (20, 255, 0))
#grapchics
fruit=pygame.image.load('chicken.gif')
mouth=pygame.image.load('a.gif')
backGr=pygame.image.load('b.gif')
#endless loop
running=True
while running:
    #code to move fruit
    if fruit_y>=460:#check if at bottom, if so prepare new fruit
        fruit_x=random.randrange(50,530,1)
        fruit_y=75
        fruit=pygame.image.load(fruitlist[random.randrange(0,2,1)])
    else:
        fruit_y+=5
    #check collision
    if fruit_y>=440:
        if fruit_x>=mouth_x and fruit_x<=mouth_x+110:
            myscore+=1
            fruit_y=600 #move it off screen
    #detect key events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):
            if (event.key==pygame.K_LEFT):
                mouth_x-=20
            if (event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT):
                mouth_x+=20
    #update screen from back first
    label2=myfont.render(str(myscore), 1, (20, 255, 0))
    window.blit(backGr,(0,0))
    window.blit(mouth, (mouth_x,440))
    window.blit(fruit,(fruit_x, fruit_y))
    window.blit(label1, (174, 537))
    window.blit(label2, (700, 157))
    window.blit(label3, (700, 400))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

The entire last section of code, from #update screen from back first, will only run when the while running: loop finishes. So you need to tab all those lines forward one.